# Italics / regular formatting with bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib, italic, bibliographystyle, roman

In my bibliography, article titles are printed in regular font, while book titles are in italics. The same is true for journal names.

Isn't usually the title of the post displayed in italics? The only solution I found is to manually use `\emph` for each title, but it should do automatically.

I am using EBGaramond and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` (with natbib package).

Comment: The bibliography style that's in use -- I gather it is `plainnat` in the case of your document -- determines how various fields of a bibliographic entry are formatted. While there are many bibliography styles exist that italicize the `title` field for entries of type `@article`, this typographical convention is by no means universal. You definitely should not encase the title fields of your article-type entries in `\emph` wrappers. If you really can't stand the formatting settings of the `plainnat` bib style, it's time for you to move on to some other style.

Comment: Use a different style. Some styles use *italics* only for book titles and journal names, as you have discovered.

Comment: A number of prescriptive style guides (APA, Chicago) require structurally similar behaviour. Roughly the idea is that stand-alone works have their title in italics, while works that are included in stand-alone works are in quotation marks or without special formatting (my rule of thumb is that if you are in a library, the title you can see without opening a book - i.e. on the cover or spine - is in italic, if you need to open the book, it's not). That's why book and journal titles are in italics, but article titles are not. So this behaviour is not per se unusual.